# what difference between ax query and select

Tags: axapta, x++, ax, dynamics-ax-2012

I'm looking for difference between **ax query** and **select** (or **while select**)
In this example i don't see what's i can not do with statement select : [the example of ax query in msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa893981%28v=ax.10%29.aspx)

I think I misunderstood the syntax of ax query ranges :'(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A (while) select is a 'one use' statement, ie, you put it inline in your code and it is used only there.

A query can be setup to require parameters and can be used multiple times throughout your class or saved into the AOT for use in any class.

Generally I only use select statements for simple queries where its not worth the effort to create a query, for anything more complex I use queries.

Comment: Complex queries (with joins) are way easier to read as code. I think the relevant issue is whether you want a dynamic query with user provided ranges. A 4 table join in a while select is okay if the query is "static".

Comment: Note: AX 2012 full text indexes are not supported in a select statement. In this (rare) case you have to use a query.